# how to capture screen of the ubuntu server to a video file while connecting it over ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, capture

I am trying to capture screen of the Ubuntu server to a video file while i am connecting it over ssh.

Using xrandr, I can identify which video outputs are connected and which ones are not connected. Assume that DP1 and HDMI1 are connected. So how to capture DP1 output to `DP1.mp4` and HDMI1 output to `HDMI1.mp4` using vlc or ffmpeg while connecting over SSH?

Answer (score 1):

Install the kazam application through `APT`:

```
sudo apt install kazam
```